# How to delete a work item relation (parent) from a child task work item via HTTP request to azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure Devops, I have a task work item which has a parent work item linked to it. I know how to do it via Azure Devops. However, I would like to know how to delete the parent task relationship from the child task work item via HTTP request to azure devops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples) rest api to remove the parent task relation from the child task.

First you need to check the parent task's index in the relations arraylist of the child task. Using [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest api and specify the `$expand=Relations` parameter to include the relations in the result. See below example in powershell script:

```
$token="PAT"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJ/_apis/wit/workitems/9?`$expand=Relations&api-version=6.1-preview.3"
$invRestMethParams = @{
    
    Uri = $uri
    Method = 'get'
    Headers= @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
  }
$res= Invoke-RestMethod @invRestMethParams

$res.relations
```

Result:

[image]

In above example, the parent task is listed as the first element in the relations arraylist of the child task. So the parent task index is 0.

Then use Work Items - Update rest api to remove the parent task relationship.

Request body:

```
$body='[
 {
    "op": "remove",
    "path": "/relations/0"  #parent task index is 0
    
  }
 ]'
```

See below example in powershell script:

```
$token="PAT"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJ/_apis/wit/workitems/9?`$expand=Relations&api-version=6.1-preview.3"

$body='[
     {
        "op": "remove",
        "path": "/relations/0"  #parent task index is 0
        
      }
     ]'

$invRestMethParams = @{
      Uri = $uri
      Method = 'PATCH'
      ContentType = 'application/json-patch+json'
      Headers= @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
      Body=$body
    }
Invoke-RestMethod @invRestMethParams
```