# Remove relation between Azure DevOps work items and commits programmatically

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api

I pushed an existing GIT repo to a new DevOps repo, inadvertently this linked all the commits with a *#{number}* on the message to the work item with that ID.

I have successfully identified (via the REST API and the CLI) all the Work Items and the relationships to the commits but...

1. `az boards work-item relation remove --id $workItemID --relation-type 'Artifact Link' --target-id $relationID --org $orgURL --yes` fails complaining that *$relationID* is not a valid work item, which is weird since *relation type* is *Artifact Link* so I don't understand why it's trying to fetch a work item.
2. Using the REST API seems rather risky because the request is done using the index of the relation; and not using an specific ID makes me very uncomfortable and I would need to validate all the changes, which is practically impossible for the amount of tickets that I'm touching.

How can I programmatically remove all these relationships with a sound approach? Preferably using the ID of the relationship

Comment: How did you identify the work items linked to specific commits? I made the same mistake ;)

Comment: `function Get-WorkItemsByRepo {
    param ([string] $organization, [string] $project, [string] $pat, [string] $repoID)

    $headers = Get-PatHeader($pat)
    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repoID/commits?includeWorkItems=true&``$top=99999&?api-version=5.0"

    $commits = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers).value
    $workItems = ($commits | where-object { $_.workItems.Count -gt 0 }) | foreach-object { $_.workItems }
    return $workItems | sort-object -property @{Expression = { [int]::Parse($_.id) } } -unique
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the Azure Boards cli extension assumes that the targetId is a work item (like parent or child) and that other relationships are not supported). It does not say so flat out in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/boards/work-item/relation?view=azure-cli-latest#az-boards-work-item-relation-remove), but the only example given for relationship type is parent and child.

> --relation-type
>
> Relation type to create. Example: parent, child.

I understand that the index based addressing is not ideal, but why would using the index of the relationship be a problem in practise?

If you start your script by [fetching the workitem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) and checking for which index the relationship has you can then go ahead and remove that relationship with a [workitem update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP).

The only reason I could see this would not work is if someone modifies the workitem in such a way that the index for the artifact link changes (like removing a relationship with a lower index) in between the get and update command, which seems highly unlikely given the short timeframe between the commands. Executing the script during off hours or an agreed time window where no other activity is allowed further lowers the risk.

If you still wish to validate that the change was carried out correct you could do that automatically as well in your script:

- After the first Get, save all relationships
- Carry out the update (removing the relationship to the commit)
- Fetch the workitem again
- Make sure the only difference in relationship is that the commit relation has been removed. If not, issue a warning/exit the script etc.

Here is a similar question which could give further insights: [How to delete a work item relation (parent) from a child task work item via HTTP request to azure devops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614421/how-to-delete-a-work-item-relation-parent-from-a-child-task-work-item-via-http)

Comment: Since the relations don't have an index property, am I just to assume that the order in which they come is the index in DevOps? Is it zero-based or one-based? Essentially, what's the best way to get the index?

Comment: It is zero-based. When you retrieve a workitem from the rest api with the `$expand` property set to `Relations` you will get an array called `relations` in the resulting json. The index of the relation in that array is the index of the relation you should use when you remove it. Please see this answer for an example implementation in Powershell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614421/how-to-delete-a-work-item-relation-parent-from-a-child-task-work-item-via-http
It is removing the parent relationship, not the commit, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I tested the Azure CLI command of [az boards work-item relation | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/boards/work-item/relation?view=azure-cli-latest#az-boards-work-item-relation-remove), it seemed to only remove the relation between work items rather than the commit links.

I have also tested the Rest API to [remove a link of a workitem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#remove-a-link) and agree it is indeed annoying to sort out the index of the link to be deleted.

If you would expect to delete **all** the commit links of your affected work item, the excel plug-in [Azure DevOps Office Integration 2019 (free)](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#other-family) may help.

[image: Excel plug-in berief steps to remove links]

Anyway, I understand it is not working in a programmatical way and may not be the a good option, if you have to find out the commit links to be deleted. Just a amicable sharing. For more information, kindly refer to the following documents.

[Connect Azure Boards to an Office client to track your work - Azure Boards | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/track-work?view=azure-devops&tabs=open-excel#excel)

[Modify Azure Boards work items in bulk with Microsoft Excel - Azure Boards | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)

Comment: This might be slightly faster than doing it from the UI but still too manual. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a catch in index based removing relations recommended by danielorn if you remove the links one by one. As each patch changes the relations list, it also shifts the relations with higher indexes down if you walk the list from start so the indexing breaks. Reverse order walk through the list works fine though.